# ApexCharts.js line chart - Show zero for missing dates

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm populating a series with "date-value pairs like this:

```
series: [{
                      name: "Price",
                      data:[
                        [1486684800000, 38],
                        [1486771200000, 0],
                        [1486857600000, 0],
                        [1486944000000, 0],
                        [1487030400000, 0],
                        [1487116800000, 58]]
                    },
```

But, when for instance I'm populating the series array with "missing dates" like this:

```
series: [{
                      name: "Price",
                      data:[
                        [1486684800000, 38],
                        [1487116800000, 58]]
                    },
```

ApexCharts will automatically fill the line, and will not fill the missing dates with zero values.

Any ideas on how to force ApexCharts to show missing dates with zero values and not "ignore" them?

Comment: You have to set minimum and maximum x-axis value

Comment: Could you please specify where exactly? https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#

Comment: Not exactly but you can take reference from this example https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/area-charts/datetime-x-axis/

Comment: @IdoS did you find a way? setting the minimum and maximum x-axis value does not seem to help

Comment: @Joshua No, unfortunately, I could not find a solution with apexCharts, so I had to prepare the data on the backend (fill missing dates with 0 values).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 2 years old, but I had simillar problem. My backend returns date formatted like YYYY-MM-DD, but you can change this pretty easy.

```
    var startDate = new Date()
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 30)
    var getDaysArray = function (start, end) {
      for (var arr = [], dt = new Date(start); dt <= new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
        const currDate = new Date(dt).toISOString().split('T')[0]
        var amount = response.data.monthly_logs.find(monthlyLog => monthlyLog.created_at__date === currDate) || 0
        if (amount) {
          amount = amount.price
        }
        arr.push({ x: new Date(dt), y: amount })
      }
      return arr
    }
    var result = getDaysArray(startDate, new Date())
```